# (Exercise 1.6 K&R) How to verfiy that getchar() != EOF IS 0 OR 1?

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I have just started to learn programming (C) as a hobby, by myself. I'm using K&R.

```
 main()
{
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
putchar(c);
}
```

> **Verify that getchar() != EOF IS 0 OR 1**

I think I understand what is happening:

1. c is assigned the next character from the keyboard
2. c is checked whether it is EOF or not
3. c is assigned 1 or 0, depending if it is EOF or not.
4. character is shown on output, or if EOF ends the program.

However, my solution is wrong, so clearly I am not understanding something:

```
main ()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

This just prints the value of the character. And also prints "10" if I press Carriage Return key.

I thought that it would print c. However, it is printing the character's value rather than the 1 or 0 value.

I know c is assigned 1 or 0 after comparing it with EOF. But I'm not sure what logic I can use to show this. It seems I need to somehow 'get out' of showing the character value, and instead show the comparison value. Does it mean I need to get out of the while loop? If so, I don't know how (and this is just a guess).

**How can I simply verify that c = 1 or 0?**

**And also, how should I know this?** There must be something fundamental that I should learn from this, I suppose.

```
main ()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF != 0 != 1)
        putchar(c);
}
```

I also did this and I think this seems to work. As it doesn't output any characters, but I'm not sure if this is the solution they are looking for...

Comment: `x != y` returns a boolean value. You can verify that it's always `1` or `0` by reading the C standard (and assuming your compiler actually follows it, I suppose.) (Although you're asking another, unrelated question about `c`, which is the value returned by `getchar`, not the value of the comparison with EOF).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I know c is assigned 1 or 0 after comparing it with EOF

No it isn't. Look:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

The expression is: `(c = getchar()) != EOF`, which contains another expression: `(c = getchar())`, which assigns to `c` the character from the keyboard. **`c` will *not* be equal to 0 or 1!** It's the result of the expression. Try this code:

```
int main()
{
   char value;
   int c;
   value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
   printf("%i\n", value);
   return 0;
}
```

This code will print the value of the expression `(c = getchar()) != EOF`. Actually, your code could be written like this:

```
int main ()
{
    int c;
    char value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    while (value)
    {
        printf("%d\n", c);
        value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expression isn't in the `while` anymore and its result is assigned to `value`. The code above and your code will produce exactly the same output.

---

**EDIT:**

```
main ()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF != 0 != 1)
        putchar(c);
}
```

The code above is not the solution! Here is the re-written code:

```
main ()
{
    int c;
    char value1;
    char value2;
    char value3;

    value1 = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    value2 = value1 != 0;
    value3 = value2 != 1;
    while (value3)
    {
        putchar(c);
        value1 = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
        value2 = value1 != 0;
        value3 = value2 != 1;
    }
}
```

So what happens?
Let's say `getchar` will return the character 'A'. This means that:

- `value1` will be equal to 1, since 'A' is different than `EOF`.
- `value2` will be equal to 1, because `value1` (which is equal to 1) is different than 0.
- `value3` will be equal to 0, because `value2` (which is equal to 1) is **not** different than 1: `while(value3)` is now `while(0)`, so no characters will be printed.

It's important to understand that you can assign to a variable the result of a comparison expression (that means an expression with at least one comparison operator), and the result of this kind of expression is 0 (for false) or 1 (for true).

---

Few words about the OP's comment:

> Hey, thanks. But K&R explicitly says "This has the undesired effect of setting c to 1 or 0". Maybe this is why I'm confused.

`c` will be assigned to 0 or 1 if the `while` looks like this:

```
while (c = getchar() != EOF)
```

The operator `!=` has a bigger priority than the operator `=`. That means that `getchar() != EOF` will be evaluated first, and then its result will be assigned to `c`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But K&R explicitly says "This has the undesired effect of setting c to 1 or 0".

Maybe this is why I'm confused.

Comment: I am starting to feel that programming is not for me. It seems too difficult to grasp even these simple concepts.

Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: @user2071506 Ah come on :) It's totally normal ! Actually the K&R is not designed to beginner. It's one of the best book but it assumes that you already have some programming experiences. The `C` language isn't the easier language to learn programming, but if you know it, you can know everything ;)

Comment: Note: `c` _could_ take on the value of 0 or 1 as many keyboards allow entry like Ctrl-@ or Ctrl A which map to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 9):

I realize the question is old but the selected answer is answering something that is not what the question is intended to be asked. (It is a different question asked from the book) I am here to clarify a few things and hope that other people who searched this question up from Google can read my answer for a better understanding of question 1-6 from The C Programming Language 2nd Edition.

The question stated **verify that getchar() != EOF IS 0 OR 1**

The book hinted that

`**c = (getchar() != EOF)**`

is equivalent to

`**c = getchar() != EOF**`

When `getchar() != EOF` is tested,

If the input is *not* `EOF`, then it should be true, hence returning a `True`, or a `1` in this sense.

And of course, if input *is* `EOF`, then `getchar() != EOF` will return a `False`, or a `0`.

That is why either `1` or `0` will be assigned into `c`.

For the "undesirable effect" mentioned in the book, because neither `1` nor `0` is the original input, this means that the original character intended to be output is *lost*, and this is undesirable.

For the exercise, use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    while ( c = getchar() != EOF ) {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
}
```

If your input is not `EOF`, then it will print `1`.

If your input is `EOF`, then the program ends.

**NOTE:** To type `EOF` in Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>

*Edit:*

A simpler solution to Exercise 1.6 of K&R.

```
printf("%d", getchar() != EOF);
```

Comment: Thank you, Sayyora, this was a much clearer explanation of the answer to 1-6 than the selected answer, which is also trying to answer stuff from the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

'c' is assigned the value from getchar and then checked for whether or not it is EOF.

If it is not assigned EOF, print the value of 'c'; if not, exist the loop.

the test for EOF does not reassign any value to 'c', it only succeeds or fails

IOW, remove your step 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here `c` is not assigned to the result of comparison.It contains the `value read form File.`

To check the result of comparison you need as follows

int result = ((c = getchar()) != EOF)

Then use the result to check it is 0 or 1.

```
printf("%d",result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having tons of trouble with this very problem.

> And also prints "10" if I press Carriage Return key.

Also, page 20 K&R states that the ASCII value for '\n' is 10.  So perhaps you are returning that value unintentionally?

Everytime I come back to it, I forget that Carriage Return key **IS NOT** EOF.

Like user Sayyora points out above, you need a key combo to signal EOF.

For Linux it is:

> Ctrl + D

Also, to kill program (in X-Term at least), it is:

> Ctrl + C

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a C source file within DevC++ 4.9.9.2.  I'm new to programming in C and I'm using  K/R 2nd Ed. as my guide.  After reviewing statements from above, I found the following lines provided me the output desired by Example 1.6/1.7.  Feel free to correct my understanding, but by picking up on the author(s) tip about use of parenthesis and printing both inside and outside the while loop, one is able to obtain a result of 1 or 0.  The last getchar() is a requirement of the Dev-C environment to hold the input/output screen open for review of printed statements.

```
main()
{
      int c; 
      while (c=getchar() !=EOF)
            printf("%d",c);
      printf("%d",c);
      getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// it will accept and print a single char, a word, a sentence...

while (c != EOF) {
  printf("\ngetchar()) != EOF) = %d -- ", ((c=getchar()) != EOF));
  putchar(c);
}

//the trick is to only call getchar() once per char and EOF value
//note: the last char is always char(10) which is invisible
```

Comment: You're presenting a solution for an admittedly newbie programmer. This should be accompanied by a detailed explanation, ideally.

Comment: Calling getchar(c) consumes a single character. So how do you print every getchar(c) and also print the EOF value for the same getchar(c) call? One way is to call getchar(c) in the printf() function itself. This allows you to cal getchar() once for each character entered while printing the resulting char and EOF. The clause in the while statement allows this but it is not very elegant. I am not sure if later versions of C will allow this, but ANSI C does. To compile with ANSI use the -ansi flag.

Comment: just realized the last char in getchar() is char(10) so it is invisible but putchar(c) treats it like any other char

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
   
int main(){
    int c;
    printf("Verifying that the expression 'c = getchar() != EOF' is: %d \n", (getchar() != EOF));
   
    return 0;
}
```

Well when you enter value to the 'c' it is != so it return '1' and when you send EOF command it returns '0'.

In my opinion this is the exercise from the book since it is in the beginning it shouldn't be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This problem cannot be solved. It is a bad and untested question.

getchar() will pause for input when stdin is empty, and thus will never return EOF.

The only way to cheat this through, is to manually input an EOF in your terminal with ctrl+d (which I don't consider a valid and intended solution).